# How to run Rails console in the test environment and load test_helper.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, shoulda

The background: I'm having some problems with Thoughtbot's "Factory Girl" gem, with is used to create objects to use in unit and other tests. I'd like to go to the console and run different Factory Girl calls to check out what's happening. For example, I'd like to go in there are do...

```
>> Factory(:user).inspect
```

I know that you can run the console in different environments...

$ script/console RAILS_ENV=test

But when I do that, Factory class is not available. It looks as though `test_helper.rb` is not getting loaded.

I tried various `require` calls including one with the absolute path to `test_helper.rb` but they fail similarly to this:

```
$ script/console RAILS_ENV=test
>> require '/Users/ethan/project/contactdb/test/test_helper.rb'
  Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - 
  /Users/ethan/project/contactdb/config/environments/RAILS_ENV=test.rb
```

Grr. Argh.

Comment: Consequently if you had placed the RAILS_ENV=test before script/console, it would have worked as you would expect.

Answer (score 220, accepted):

**For Rails < 3.0**

Run `script/console --help`. You'll notice that the syntax is `script/console [environment]`, which in your case is `script/console test`.

I'm not sure if you have to require the test helper or if the test environment does that for you, but with that command you should at least be able to boot successfully into the test env.

As a sidenote: It is indeed kind of odd that the various binaries in script/ has different ways of setting the rails environment.

**For Rails 3 and 4**

Run `rails c test`.  Prepend `bundle exec` if you need this for the current app environment.

**For Rails 5 and 6**

Run `rails console -e test`.

Comment: In rails 3, it's just `rails console [environment]`

Comment: It's a little inconsistent because to start the server you type `rails server -e test`

Comment: In Rails 5 this still works.

And, you do need to load at least some parts of your environment -- in my case ```features/support/helpers.rb``` wasn't automagically loaded. Also, ```Rack::Test``` isn't loaded.

Answer (score 62):

In Rails 3, just do `rails console test` or `rails console production` or `rails console development` (which is the default).

Answer (score 15):

For Rails 5.2.0: "Passing the environment's name as a regular argument is deprecated and will be removed in the next Rails version. Please, use the -e option instead."

```
rails c -e test
```

Answer (score 10):

```
script/console test
```

Should be all you need.

Answer (score 4):

You can specify the environment in which the console command should operate.

```
rails c [environment]
```

Examples

1) For Staging

```
rails c staging
```

2) For Production

```
rails c production
```

For source & detailed description:   [The Rails Command Line](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-console)

Answer (score 3):

David Smith is correct, just do

```
script/console test
```

The help command will show why this works:

```
$ script/console -h
Usage: console [environment] [options]
    -s, --sandbox                    Rollback database modifications on exit.
        --irb=[irb]                  Invoke a different irb.
        --debugger                   Enable ruby-debugging for the console.
```

It's the **[environment]** bit.

Answer (score 2):

I share the asker's pain. There are really three separate questions here, some of which are addressed, some not:

1. How do you start the console in the test environment?

   For recent Rails versions, `bundle exec rails c test`, or alternative syntaxes for that.
2. How do you ensure that test/test_helper.rb is loaded into that console session?

   Something like `require './test/test_helper'` ought to do it.

   For me, this returns true, indicating that it was not already loaded when I started the console. If that statement returns false, then you just wasted a few keystrokes, but you're still good to go.
3. Once test_helper is loaded, how do you call the methods defined in it?

   In a typical test_helper, the custom methods are typically defined as instance methods of ActiveSupport::TestCase. So if you want to call one of them, you need an instance of that class. By trial and error, ActiveSupport::TestCase.new has one required parameter, so...pass it something.

   If your test_helper has a method called create_user, you could invoke it this way:
   `ActiveSupport::TestCase.new("no idea what this is for").create_user`

Comment: Rather than trial or error - use the rails API guide to find what it needs http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TestCase.html ... it's probably test order which is `:random` by default

Comment: There's only those two class methods described for ActiveSupport::TestCase, so I'm unclear on what class/module it inherits its `initialize` method from. But it looks like the parameter it expects gets stored as `@NAME` on the created object.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you installed the GEM and you added the following line either in your environment.rb or test.rb file.

```
config.gem "thoughtbot-factory_girl", :lib => "factory_girl", :source => "http://gems.github.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

Test Env

```
rails console test # or just rails c test
```

Developement Env

```
rails console # or just rails c
```

Answer (score 0):

Command to run rails console test environment is

```
rails c -e test
```

or

```
RAILS_ENV=test rails c
```

if you are facing problem something like

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   Mysql2::Error: Table 'DB_test.users' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `users`
```

then you should first prepare your test DB by running

```
bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
```