# How can I start the rails console and use the testing database exclusively?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to start the rails console and create database entries in a database that isn't the default database, such as the testing database. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

To start console in `test` environment:

```
ruby script/console test 
ruby script/console production
```

To run rake tasks in `test` environment:

```
rake db:create RAILS_ENV=test 
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```

In Rails 3 and 4 you can use:

```
rails console test
rails c test
```

In Rails 5 you can use:

```
rails console -e test
rails c -e test
```

Comment: For completeness, `rails console -e test` or `rails c -e test` also works (in Rails 5.2 https://stackoverflow.com/a/53127882/188574)

> Passing the environment's name as a regular argument is deprecated and will be removed in the next Rails version. Please, use the -e option instead.

Answer (score 10):

You can pass the environment as `RAILS_ENV=test`:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rails console
```

Or:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rails c
```

You can also do:

```
$ bundle exec rails console test
```

Or:

```
$ bundle exec rails c test
```

You can see like

```
Loading test environment (Rails 3.2.8)
1.9.3p327 :001 >
```

Answer (score 8):

in Rails 6 the syntax has changed for this

```
rails c -e test
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ RAILS_ENV=test ./script/console
```